# Using function from FindMatlab.cmake

Tags: matlab, cmake

I'm trying to use `matlab_get_all_valid_matlab_roots_from_registry()` from `FindMatlab.cmake` and print the results using this script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(Matlab REQUIRED)

matlab_get_all_valid_matlab_roots_from_registry(a b)

message("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
message(STATUS " !!!!! ${a} ${b} ${Matlab_ROOT_DIR} ####")
message("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

Is it necessary that I first call `find_package()` before calling `matlab_get_all_valid_matlab_roots_from_registry()` ?

The output of the script doesn't print the contents of the variables `a` and `b` that are return values of that function. This is the output:

```
1> Command line: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017

\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe  -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\AppTeam\CMakeBuilds\6f0f93b4-4e73-e838-98c8-2bfd807d82bf\install\x64-Debug (default)"  -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\AppTeam\Documents\bil\matlab\codegen\lib\mcadd"
1> Working directory: C:\Users\AppTeam\CMakeBuilds\6f0f93b4-4e73-e838-98c8-2bfd807d82bf\build\x64-Debug (default)
1> --  !!!!!   C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018b ####
1> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
1> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
1> -- Configuring done
```

It seems that `Matlab_ROOT_DIR` variable is OK, but I would like to find all MATLAB installations by using `matlab_get_all_valid_matlab_roots_from_registry()` but the output variables are not displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```
matlab_get_all_valid_matlab_roots_from_registry(matlab_versions, matlab_roots)
```

where `matlab_versions` is an input argument, and should contain a list of the MATLAB versions you want the roots for. Since you pass an empty list as input, you get zero roots back.

According to [the sources](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindMatlab.cmake), `matlab_versions` comes either from `extract_matlab_versions_from_registry_brute_force` or `matlab_extract_all_installed_versions_from_registry`. The former is an internal macro, and the latter is a function available only on Windows. So on Windows you can do:

```
find_package(Matlab REQUIRED)
set(matlab_versions)
matlab_extract_all_installed_versions_from_registry(ON matlab_versions)
matlab_get_all_valid_matlab_roots_from_registry(matlab_versions, matlab_roots)
message(STATUS " !!!!! ${matlab_versions} ${matlab_roots} ${Matlab_ROOT_DIR} ####")
```

Also, yes, you do need to issue `find_package(Matlab)` to make the functions defined therein available.

---

**Note** regarding `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)`:

If a user has a version of CMake that old (2.8 was released in 2009!), you might find that the user's MATLAB will not be found. The script has a list of known versions of MATLAB to look for, so you need to always use the newest version of the script to find the newest versions of MATLAB (or explicitly add information about the release you are using). [The version of the `FindMatlab.cmake` script in 2009](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/c4bb9c9d42d7dac1e1e28d488b933eae304e202d/Modules/FindMatlab.cmake) explicitly looked for MATLAB 7.0 and 7.0 SP1, which were released in 2004, already 5 years outdated at that time, and didn't have the possibility to look for newer versions of MATLAB. This script also did not define a function `matlab_get_all_valid_matlab_roots_from_registry`.

So, in general, I recommend that you look for the CMake features you are using, and require a version of CMake that supports those features. I know it is common to see "require 2.8" in CMake scripts, but this is not always the best choice. In the case of MATLAB, it certainly is not the best choice.